# Multisheet design power rail as port or as power port

Tags: altium

I am learning [Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/) and now I am working on some multisheet pcb project, which consists of `Power Supply` among other things, which is implemented with 
[Texas Instruments's UA7805 Regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua78.pdf) for `+5V/1.5A` power supply rail. This rail is named in schematic as `+5V_DIGITAL`. However, because of multisheet design (with root sheet), how do I declare this power rail in `Altium`, as [Power port](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-PowerPort((Power+Port))_AD):
[image: power port]
or as [Port](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Port((Port))_AD):
[image: Port]
? If rail should/must be declared as `Port`, then what type of port it is (`Unspecified`, `Output` or `Bidirectional`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports are mainly for signals, not rails. I always use option #1, with a power port. The benefit to this is that (depending on your project settings) the power ports are global so you don't need any sort of sheet-to-sheet connector to connect the power ports between sheets. The connection is implicit.